# Send data in a vanilla js ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand the problem when sending data in httpc.send I tried JSON.stringify but nothing to do the return is always null. The different subjects concerning ajax do not have the area to have a problem.

```
var data = {
    concat_operation: params
};
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
var url = "calcul.php";


httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
        console.log(httpc.response); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
        // console.log(JSON.parse(httpc.responseText)); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
        var serverResponse = JSON.parse(httpc.responseText);
        console.log(serverResponse);
    }
};
httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST
console.log(data);
httpc.send(data);
```

However, I managed to do it in Jquery. A processing must be supported by Jquery that I haven't thought of?

```
var data = {
    concat_operation: concat_number
};
$.post("calcul.php", data , function(response){
    var result = response.result;
    $('.parent').before(`<div class="result">${result}</div>`);
}, "json")
```

UPDATE : in the end it was a php processing that I missed in addition to passing it in JSON I put it here if it can be useful to anyone:

JS:

```
function callPHP(params) {
            
            // var data = {
            //     concat_operation: params
            //   };
              var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
              var url = "calcul.php";
              
              httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
                if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
                  console.log(httpc.response); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
                  // console.log(JSON.parse(httpc.responseText)); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
                  var serverResponse = JSON.parse(httpc.responseText);
                  console.log(serverResponse);
                  console.log(serverResponse.result);
                  var result = serverResponse.result;
                  $('.parent').before(`<div class="result">${result}</div>`);
                }
              };
              httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST
              httpc.setRequestHeader('Conten-Type', 'application/json')
              httpc.send(JSON.stringify(params));
              
              
        }
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $result = eval('return '.$data.';');
    $arr_result = ["result" => $result];
    echo json_encode($arr_result);
```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Have you considered using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? Example: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post

Comment: I don't mind trying the fetch() as well but I would like to find a solution rather than working around the problem :) . I would like to be able to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the browser **network tab** for the version that works and compare with the version that doesn't work.   Equally debug/step-through your service php to see what it is receiving in each case.

Comment: What type of data is `params`? Please explain what the problem actually is because it is not clear what is or is not happening

Comment: params is a character string corresponding to a calculation (ex:'5+2') this calculation is sent to php to carry out the calculation and return the result only upon receipt of data php tells me that $_POST['concat_operation'] is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to happily send data to a PHP script using a FormData object which can then be processed in PHP by accessing $_POST variables like this

```
<?php
    
    #----------
    #calcul.php
    #----------
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['concat_operation'] ) ){
        $op=$_POST['concat_operation'];
        $response=array();
        
        /* do stuff with supplied data */
        $response['foo']='bar';
        
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit(json_encode($response));
    }
?>
```

The Fetch / Ajax code:

```
let fd=new FormData();
    fd.set('concat_operation',params);
    
fetch('calcul.php',{ method:'post',body:fd })
    .then(r=>r.json())
    .then(json=>{
        console.log(json)
        /* do stuff with response */
    })
    .catch(alert)
```

This would send a single POST parameter named `concat_operation` with whatever data is in `params` and within the PHP code would be accessed using `$_POST['concat_operation']` - given that the URL supplied to the `fetch` call does not begin with either a slash or `./` means that both scripts (calcul.php and script sending ajax request) are in the same directory. Use the console tools to check for errors and to analyse the HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the headers correctly and send the stringified data

```
 httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST
 httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 httpc.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: yes I have already tried with and without nothing changes.

Comment: Why do you think you *have* to convert the data to JSON?  OPs working code does not send as JSON so it should be assumed that the server-side won't accept/understand a JSON string.  The `}, "json")` part of OPs code is the "*data expected from the server*"

Comment: I've just started so I don't have all the basics yet but I thought that JSON was the most practical way to share data between various languages. So should I send it in integer or simply string?

Comment: No, apologies for the confusion.  JSON is good - JSON *is* a "simple string".   I do suggest you get it working *first* with just a simple "hello" string, then move up to multiple values / compound JSON.   Your `$.post` code does not currently *send* data as JSON - so your php (probably) won't recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you lost something, the param type  of send method could be String ,FormData,Blob and so on,but not an Object,In addition you must set Conten-Type  to let the service knowing your data type ,the function transformData in below will return a String to fit the content-type setting.

```js
var data = {
  concat_operation: params
};
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
var url = "calcul.php";
httpc.setRequestHeader('Conten-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
  if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
    console.log(httpc.response); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
    // console.log(JSON.parse(httpc.responseText)); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
    var serverResponse = JSON.parse(httpc.responseText);
    console.log(serverResponse);
  }
};
httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST
console.log(data);
httpc.send(transformData(data));

function transformData(data) {
  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    let res = ''
    for (const key in data) {
      if (res) res += '&'
      res += key + '=' + data[key]
    }
    return res
  }
  return data
}
```